# Hibernate - Index on Multiple columns with sort order

Tags: java, database, hibernate, sorting, jpa

I have the following code :

```
@Table(appliesTo = "MyTable", indexes = {
  @Index(name = "MultipleColumnsIndex", columnNames = { "column1", "columns2" })})
```

Note : it's Hibernate Table.

From looking at the created table in Database I can see the index - both columns order is ASC.
Is it possible to sort column1 by ASC order and column2 by DESC order ?

Answer (score 1):

This is bug in hibernate 5.2.10 and fixed in 5.2.13 [HHH-11913](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11913)

Answer (score 0):

It worked in hibernate 4.3.8.Final

```
@Table(appliesTo = "MyTable",indexes= {
     @Index(name = "MultipleColumnsIndex", columnNames = { "column1", "columns2 desc" })
})
```

But it's not working in hibernate 5.2.10.Final