# Hibernate index with DESC order

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, indexing, jpa-2.1

is there a way to create multicolumn index with one column with DESC order? I've tried this (annotations from javax.persistence package):

```
@Table(name = some_table
  indexes = {
    @Index(name = "idx_multi_column", columnList = "column1, column2, column3"),
    @Index(name = "idx_multi_column", columnList = "column1, column2, column3 DESC")
  }
)
```

But it creates both indexes with **column3 asc** - DESC is ignored. I'm using:

Hibernate 4.3.10
Hibernate JPA 2.1 api

Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I wasn't able to hack it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition - that is [the JPA specification](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf)¹ document aka JSR 338 - there is a way to annotate the desired behaviour, exactly as you described in your question. Citing from the specification, section *11.1.23 Index Annotation*, page 452:

---

> The `@Index` annotation is used in schema generation. [..] the Index annotation
> may be used to specify the ordering of the columns in the index for the primary key.

```
@Target({}) @Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Index {
 String name() default "";
 String columnList();
 boolean unique() default false;
}
```

> The syntax of the columnList element is a column_list, as follows:

```
column::= index_column [,index_column]*
index_column::= column_name [ASC | DESC]
```

> The **persistence provider** must observe the specified ordering of the columns.

> If *ASC* or *DESC* is not specified, *ASC* (ascending order) is assumed.

---

### Conclusion

Any persistence provider must (should) respect this requirement to be conform with the JPA spec. Therefore, I can imagine that Hibernate in version 4.3.10 did either (a) suffer from a bug, or (b) did not respect the spec in that particular point.

### Ideas

- Try again with a more recent release, say Hibernate 5+, e.g. the [current release 5.4.21](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.4/)
- Try with another JPA provider, say [EclipseLink](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) or [OpenJPA](https://openjpa.apache.org).
- Check whether your compiled classes were run/tested with the correct syntax in place. Maybe, they might have been run/tested with an outdated version?

Hope it helps.

*Footnotes*

¹ In version 2.2 or the previous version 2.1/2.0

Comment: Yeah, it should be fixed in **5.4** ([SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53644447/1104612), [Hibernate issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11913)).